# Can't set grub as default on BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 22.04

I have a samsung laptop (S Book E30) with UEFI and secure boot disabled and for some reason I can't set grub to boot as default instead of Windows Boot Manager on BIOS. When I go to BIOS, I set up the ubuntu entry as default and save, but when I restart, it boots into Windows, and when I get back into the BIOS, it says that Windows Boot Manager is as default.

Comment: I suggest that you read the documentation for your motherboard or consult with support options for your motherboard/hardware. Setting boot priority in BIOS is a function of your motherboard and isn't a part of Ubuntu or any other operating system. There's a lot of variability in motherboard settings so it helps to read the documentation.

Comment: @Nmath Entirely correct but the reported situation isn't unheard of. There are a few laptop exhibiting that behavior for mainstream brands like HP to the niche MaiBenBen, with Intel or AMD, there's no rhyme or reason other than a flawed UEFI. That a Samsung does the same is plausible. In this situations there's nothing to do, just use the one-time boot menu / boot override menu each time you need to boot UBuntu.

Comment: Yeah but I already had an installation of Ubuntu on this laptop and GRUB was the default, but now I reinstalled it because of a problem that I did and it does not boot automatically on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please add information to your original posting, not in comments or "answers".  Did you try setting a supervisor password, and maybe then getting access to actions not allowed without one?

Comment: If nothing else works you can install 'Grub2Win' in Windows and set that as the default bootloader. Set it up so this boots in Ubuntu. At least then you can use your Ubuntu OS.